# Subtract exactly one year from a POSIXct object

Tags: r, date, data.table

lets say we have this date "2014-05-11 14:45:00 UTC". I would like to get the exact POSIXct object for 1 year before so "2013-05-11 14:45:00 UTC".

My first thought is to create a whole new POSIXct object by subtracting one from the year bit and pasting it together with the remainder of the string and then creating a new POSIXct object with that string like so:

```
time <- as.POSIXct("2014-05-11 14:45:00 UTC",tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
newTime <- as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(as.numeric(substr(time,1,4)) - 1),substr(time,5,19),sep=""),tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
```

this works fine (except in case of leap years!) but the thing is I need to do this in a large data.table for each row and preferably put the results right back in data.table.
Is there any other way of subtracting a year off an object like this?

Some extra I need to apply this to a data.table like this one:

```
          Time
 1: 1349206200
 2: 1349207100
 3: 1349208000
 4: 1349208900
 5: 1349209800
 6: 1349210700
 7: 1349211600
 8: 1349212500
 9: 1349213400
10: 1349214300
11: 1349215200
```

but this happens when I do:

```
SOdata[,Time:=as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(as.numeric(substr(Time,1,4)) - 1),substr(Time,5,19),sep=""),tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01"))]
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I am guessing I need to use something like lapply, but I always mess up syntax when using that function. So does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested the other answers, but the following should work as required regardless of leap years:

```
time <- as.POSIXct("2014-05-11 14:45:00 UTC",tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
time <- as.POSIXlt(time)
time$year <- time$year - 1
time <- as.POSIXct(time)
#[1] "2013-05-11 14:45:00 UTC"
```

With Gabor's leap year example:

```
time <- as.POSIXct("2012-02-29 14:45:00 UTC",tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
time <- as.POSIXlt(time)
time$year <- time$year - 1
time <- as.POSIXct(time)
#[1] "2011-03-01 14:45:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 9):

`lubridate` is your friend.

```
library(lubridate)
time <- as.POSIXct("2014-05-11 14:45:00 UTC",tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
time-dyears(1)
#[1] "2013-05-11 14:45:00 UTC"
time+dyears(1)
#[1] "2015-05-11 14:45:00 UTC"
```

For leap years

```
> x <- as.POSIXct(c("2012-02-28", "2012-02-29"), tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")
> x - dyears(1)
[1] "2011-02-28 UTC" "2011-03-01 UTC"
```

Comment: On my system, the lubridate approach returns `NA` using the leap year date in Gabor's answer (2012-02-29). Can you get that to work?

Comment: 'dyears()' seems to be more stable than 'years()'.

Answer (score 4):

`seq` in base can be used:

```
LastYr <- function(x) seq(x, length = 2, by = "-1 year")[2]
toPOSIXct <- function(x) as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01")

# example 1

LastYr(as.POSIXct("2012-02-28"))
## [1] "2011-02-28 EST"

# example 2 - leap year

LastYr(as.POSIXct("2012-02-29"))
## [1] "2011-03-01 EST"

# example 3 - vector case

x <- as.POSIXct(c("2012-02-28", "2012-02-29")) # test data
toPOSIXct(sapply(x, LastYr))
## [1] "2011-02-28 EST" "2011-03-01 EST"

# example 4 - data.table shown in question

DT[, Time := sapply(toPOSIXct(Time), LastYr)]
```

**Revised** simplified using functions `LastYr` and `toPOSIXct`.

Answer (score 2):

or you can try, in base R :

```
> time + as.difftime(52*7+1,units="days")
[1] "2015-05-11 14:45:00 UTC"

> time - as.difftime(52*7+1,units="days")
[1] "2013-05-11 14:45:00 UTC"
```

of course, it would be easier if units could be years...