# How to subtract a number of days from a date-time?

Tags: r, datetime

When using R how can I subtract a number of days from a date-time with clock time 
written in the following way: 2013-06-13 08:24:00.

E.g. subtract one day from 2013-06-13 08:24:00 to obtain 2013-06-12 08:24:00.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550315/subtract-exactly-one-year-from-a-posixct-object

Comment: How do you want to consider leap seconds?

Answer (score 3):

```
library(lubridate)
x <- as.POSIXct("2013-06-13 08:24:00")

x - ddays(1) - dminutes(24)
#[1] "2013-06-12 08:00:00 EEST"
```