# Data manipulation: Select users based on variables

Tags: r, nlp, data-manipulation, analysis

I am currently working on a machine learning project. I have a large dataset that was scraped off the forum www.stormfront.com. The dataset has 7 columns: stormfront_self_content (forum posts), stormfront_lang_id, stormfront_publication_date, stormfront_topic, stormfront_docid, stormfront_category, stormfront_user.

I want to select a set of users that have been registered on the forum for more than one year and
that have written more than 500 posts, but I am not sure how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Dataset example]

Comment: please add a sample of your data with `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: Maybe `dataset[dataset$forumposts > 500, ]`?

Comment: I have added a sample of the data.

Comment: I agree with the <500,  but how do I select those that have been registers for over a year?

Comment: use something like `(Sys.time() - stormfront_publication_date) > 365` for the second condition.

Comment: we need to consider [leap years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27550856/6574038), though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have some `id` column which represents each user, we can `group_by` each `id` select groups which have more than 500 rows and the number of days between `max` and `min` time between their publication date is greater than 365.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(stormfront_publication_date = ymd_hms(stormfront_publication_date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() > 500 & difftime(max(stormfront_publication_date), 
                    min(stormfront_publication_date),units = 'days') > 365)
```